# how to handle large array size in struct

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

i am working on a code which increases size of diagonal elements by 1
here is the working implementation
consider 5x5 matrix

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct abc
{
  int b[100];
}arr[100];
int main()
{

  for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    arr[i].b[i]+=1;
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
      cout<<arr[i].b[j]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
  }
  //system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

The code works fine for small range of arr,but i need it to work for 10^5.Any Suggestions?

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you need here.

Are you asking for how to represent a matrix of size [100000][100000] in memory?

Comment: consider it as 2-D array

Comment: consider using vector. its efficient and lives in the heap, without memory-leak problems

Answer (score 1):

I think its better to perform such memory allocations on the heap.

Comment: In a question about C++, `malloc` is almost never the answer.